# video lectures on Lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, self-learning

Is there any video lecture on first course on Lie algebra available online? , by the first course I mean, The complete book of Introduction of Lie algebra and its representation theory by James E.Humphreys.

Comment: You may ask Humphreys himself in mathoverflow (he's an active user)!

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for these videos, but you can look for it in these videos from IMPA:

- Introduction to Lie Algebras, Reimundo Heluani:
http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=programa-de-verao-2011-introduction-to-lie-algebra

Maybe it's also an alternative:
- Lie Groups, Representation Theory and Symmetric Spaces; Wolfgang Ziller
http://video.impa.br/index.php?page=doutorado2012-liegroups

both links are videos for download

Comment: @user164052 thanks a lot. can you suggest some good lecture notes also? if possible about rep thy of lie algebras or about reflection groups?

Comment: If you're going to watch Heluani classes, my suggestion would be:
email him explaining you intend to watch the video classes available on IMPA website and asking if he could suggest some lecture notes to guide you in the classes...
Here is his page: http://w3.impa.br/~heluani/
I don't know what lectures notes I could indicate...

Comment: @user164052 thanks a lot again for your suggestions. I will mail him.

Answer (score 2):

You can find video lectures, problem sets and some notes here:

https://sites.google.com/site/anupamk182/liealgebra