# Video lecture for Lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, self-learning

I hope to look for a recorded video lecture about Lie algebra, which can cover the materials of Introduction of Lie algebra and its representation theory by Humphreys. I noticed a similar question raised about ten years ago:
[video lectures on Lie algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563565/video-lectures-on-lie-algebra)
The links there no longer work. Is there any available source now?

Comment: [Jonathan Evans](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_4R2IuNuuRgJb00X2J53Iq9qe7k1nyr) has a long playlist, I have watched the first 11 and thought they were easy to understand. I have no idea how it compares to Humphreys' book though.

Comment: Volodymyr (Walter) Mazorchuk has a playlist [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn6dA-hP_G8RvWJYKeEKOPlKF240j3AEO). I haven't watched these, but I've seen his lectures on monoidal categories and representations and they're quite thorough.

Comment: I have to admit I am already put off by Mazorchuk's misuse of a long fraktur s instead of the correct and simple $\mathfrak{s}$ at the end of syllables. I wonder how he even created that character, it's not easy (and, as said, occasionally wrong).